# Keeping the same indices as the axis when resizing an image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

If I have an image, let's say

```
im = np.ones((10,10))
```

When I plot this using imshow, everything is dandy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

What I want is to be able to look at a specific part of the matrix, and keep the axis the same as the indices used to access the matrix

```
plt.imshow(im[2:5, 5:8])
plt.show()
```

This should give me a matrix with a y-axis of 5,6,7 and a x-axis of 2,3,4.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `extent` option: `plt.imshow(im[2:5, 5:8],extent=[2,4,5,7])`. `extent` takes the form of `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]`.